# Plotting specific variables from a tibble

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am hoping to make a plot from a large tibble, which only contains specific terms. Specifically, I have a column titled "media" where there are 7 types of media. I want to plot only the media types that contain "SW" (I have both DW and DW75). I was able to plot each media individually as well as all media together, but not calling specific terms from the media column.

Each unique chemical listed under "chem" should be its own plot. This is the script I used to plot the combined plots.

```
PlotChem<-function(MatrixDataCompiled){
  ggplot(data=MatrixDataCompiled,aes(x=LogConc, color = Media))+
    theme_bw()+
    geom_point(aes(y = LogArea))+
    geom_smooth(aes(y = LogArea), method = lm, se = TRUE)+ 
    ggtitle(paste("Calibration curve for",MatrixDataCompiled$Chem[1]))
}

for(i in unique(MatrixDataCompiled$Chem)){
  ChemDataComplied<-MatrixDataCompiled[MatrixDataCompiled$Chem==i,]
  loglm75<-lm(data=ChemDataComplied,LogArea~LogConc)
  PlotChem(ChemDataComplied)
  ggsave(PlotChem(ChemDataComplied),filename=paste(ChemDataComplied$Chem[1],"Chemical Cal Curve.png"))
}
``
```

Comment: Hello Rebecca. Can you please use dput() to share a sample of your data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that feature, but will explore. For the time being I attached a screen shot of the tibble for referenc.

Comment: We unfortunately can't work from an image. If your dataset is called `MatrixDataCompiled`, then type the line `dput(MatrixDataCompiled)` into the R console. Then you should edit your question and copy-paste the output into your question; the output will begin with "structure".

Comment: The output of dput is not related to the table, and is missing the important information that I am asking about and is too long to add

Comment: You can use head() to share a smaller dataframe. If your dataframe is named 'df' you could use `dput(head(df, 100))` where 100 is the number of rows you include, and can be changed as needed to make a useable data set.

Comment: This worked much better, specifically I am trying to make indivdual "chem" plots with only media that is called "DW" or "DW75"

Answer (score 0):

This sample of the dataset only has one chemical (FOSA), so this output may not be exactly what you're looking for. It should produce one facet (individual chart) for each chemical in 'Chem'. I didn't see any DW75 in this chunk of the data so I am filtering for STD, just to demonstrate this one approach more clearly. You can substitute DW75 or other specific media from your full data set of course.

```
df %>%
  filter(Media == "DW" | Media == "STD") %>%
  ggplot(aes(LogConc, LogArea, color = Media)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Chem)
```

Comment: Yeah, the data is very large, there are 19 chem total but how its sorted right now, the FOSA is the "top" of the table. For this I have the for loop to make each plot specific to each chem. - Though this code works, it isn't exactly what we need. Is it possible to modify the example code to allow for the inclusion of confidence intervals etc? When I try to apply the filter function to the already proposed code, it plots all media in the tibble, not what I specified to filter.

Comment: DWPlotting <-function(MatrixDataCompiled){
  MatrixDataCompiled %>%
  filter(Media == "DW" | Media == "DW75") %>%
  ggplot(aes(LogConc, LogArea, color = Media)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE)
  ggtitle(paste("DW Calibration curve for",MatrixDataCompiled$Chem[1]))
}

Comment: for(i in unique(MatrixDataCompiled$Chem)){
  ChemDataComplied<-MatrixDataCompiled[MatrixDataCompiled$Chem==i,]
  loglmComplied<-lm(data=ChemDataComplied,LogArea~LogConc)
  PlotChem(ChemDataComplied)
  ggsave(PlotChem(ChemDataComplied),filename=paste(ChemDataComplied$Chem[1],"DW Cal Curve.png"))
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `facet_grid()` to get a matrix of the combinations of Chem and Media without the need for the separate plot titles.

```
df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Media %in% c("DW", "DW75")) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=LogConc, color = Media)) +
        theme_bw() +
        geom_point(aes(y = LogArea)) +
        geom_smooth(
            aes(y = LogArea), method = lm, se = TRUE, formula = "y~x"
        ) + 
        facet_grid(Media~Chem)
```